# DataFrames.jl - leftjoin() - retain left dataframe index positioning

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

Using `leftjoin()` to join two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 = DataFrame(x1 = collect(1:1:10), x2 = fill(1.0,10))

Row │ x1     x2      
     │ Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1      1.0
   2 │     2      1.0
   3 │     3      1.0
   4 │     4      1.0
   5 │     5      1.0
   6 │     6      1.0
   7 │     7      1.0
   8 │     8      1.0
   9 │     9      1.0
  10 │    10      1.0

df2 = DataFrame(x1 = collect(1:2:10), x2 = fill(1.0,5))

Row │ x1     x2      
     │ Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1      1.0
   2 │     3      1.0
   3 │     5      1.0
   4 │     7      1.0
   5 │     9      1.0

out_df = leftjoin(df1,df2, on = :x1, makeunique=true)
```

for output:

```
Row │ x1     x2        x2_1      
     │ Int64  Float64?  Float64?  
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     1       1.0        1.0
   2 │     3       1.0        1.0
   3 │     5       1.0        1.0
   4 │     7       1.0        1.0
   5 │     9       1.0        1.0
   6 │     2       1.0  missing   
   7 │     4       1.0  missing   
   8 │     6       1.0  missing   
   9 │     8       1.0  missing   
  10 │    10       1.0  missing
```

My question is with `df1` being 10 rows and `df2` being 5 rows. I am electing `df1` to be the 'master' df if you will and wish to retain its original index positioning and when join `df1` to `df2` - `df2` slots into the `df1` matches and puts in missing values on non-matches but retaining df1 index positioning for output:

```
Row │ x1     x2        x2_1      
     │ Int64  Float64?  Float64?  
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     1       1.0        1.0
   2 │     2       1.0        missing
   3 │     3       1.0        1.0
   4 │     4       1.0        missing   
   5 │     5       1.0        1.0
   6 │     6       1.0        missing   
   7 │     7       1.0        1.0
   8 │     8       1.0        missing   
   9 │     9       1.0        1.0   
  10 │    10       1.0        missing
```

There anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature we plan to add in the future, see https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/2753.

For now, before we add the requested functionality, add a column to your left data frame with row id (in your example there is already such a column `:x1`) and sort the result on this column.